# Load extension after Angular loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a Chrome extension that adds event listeners to elements on a page that uses Angular 1.2.10, with code like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
var switchButton = document.getElementById('switch');
  switchButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    reached = !reached;
  });
});
```

It works fine normally, but if I start to load the page and switch tabs, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. It appears that the Angular app doesn't completely load until I switch back to the original tab, but the `load` event fires anyways.

How can I wait until the Angular app has finished populating the DOM to add my click listener to the `'switch'` element?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you tried `$scope.$apply()` with your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom directive:

```
app.directive("addReachClick", function () {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
        elem.on('click', (event) => {
          reached = !reached;
        });
    }
})
```

Then declare that directive on the element:

```
<div id="switch" add-reach-click>
</div>
```

The AngularJS compile service will automatically invoke the `postLink` function when it adds element to the DOM.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).